# Filter and save in-place, lines with value less than or equal ≤‎X in a specific column and with header

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, gawk

I have simulation files that I want to filter one column with only numbers that are less than 100. My files look like this:

```
Time    Node    AppId   SeqNo   Type    DelayS  DelayUS RetxCount   HopCount
0.00209295  4   1   0   LastDelay   0.00209295  2092.95 1   2
0.00209295  4   1   0   FullDelay   0.00209295  2092.95 1   2
0.101892    4   1   1   LastDelay   0.00189179  1891.8  1   2
0.101892    4   1   1   FullDelay   0.00189179  1891.8  1   2
... (1000's of lines)
```

I'm filtering the file by the column 'RetxCount' using `cat app-delays-trace.txt | awk ' $8 <= 100 ' > output.txt`.

Question 1 - How do I keep the header (aka first row)?

Question 2 - How do I save the output to the same filename? Right now, if I do `cat ... | awk ... > sameFilename.txt` the file comes out empty.

Comment: Don't `cat file | awk 'stuff'`; just `awk 'stuff' file`.

Comment: What do the greater-than signs in the title mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` by itself will do this nicely:

```
awk 'NR==1 { print } NR != 1 && $8 <= 100 { print }' inputfile > outputfile
```

You cannot output to the file which you are reading from, as the `>` redirect will create a new empty file before it starts to read it for input.  So:

```
awk 'NR==1 { print } NR != 1 && $8 <= 100 { print }' inputfile > outputfile ; mv outputfile inputfile
```

But only *after* you have either backed up `inputfile` or ensured the output is as desired.

Comment: This was the simpler solution that worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: you could use `head -1` or add an "OR" condition to `awk`, ie: `|| $1 == Time`

Question 2: when you have a command like: `command > file.txt`, bash's first operation is to open file.txt.  `>` is a non appending redirect is truncating your file.  Then the rest of the command is ran on the now empty file.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to first question: add `NR==1` to print header as well.

```
awk '$8 <= 100 || NR==1' infile
```

Answer to second question with a hacky way and using FILENAME parameter.

```
awk '($8 <= 100 || NR==1){print >FILENAME}' infile
```